# How to differ Chinese with GetLocaleInfo?

Tags: windows, mfc, internationalization

I want to get an ISO 639-1 language string from an LCID. The problem is that 2052 (Simplified Chinese) and 1028 (Traditional Chinese) both return zh (Chinese) instead of zh-CN and zh-TW.

The code I use is

```
WCHAR  locale[8];
GetLocaleInfoW(lcid, LOCALE_SISO639LANGNAME, locale, 8);
```

Is there a way to get the right code?

Answer (score 1):

ISO 639-1 specifies 2-letter language names, so `GetLocaleInfo()` correctly returns "zh" for both Simplified and Traditional Chinese - they are not differentiated in the ISO 639-1 spec.

A call with `LOCALE_SNAME` instead always returns a string also containing the sub-tag, eg "de-DE" or "de-AT".

Everything else, for example a 2-letter tag for "most" languages and 4-letter one (xx-YY) for some "exceptions" (like Chinese - and which other ones?), is something custom and would therefore require custom code.

Comment: Thanks. But it's an old project I'm updating so I don't have LOCALE_SNAME. But I solved it with LOCALE_SISO639LANGNAME and LOCALE_SISO3166CTRYNAME instead.